# what is the sequence of execution at run time for boolean expression which contains and/or

Tags: java, c++11

i want to know how the boolean expressions are executed at run time.
i mean if we have a boolean expression like `flag= a>c&&b<s;` ,do the next expression is being looked up or it will be ignored ,if the first condition is false?..
.
i need this info because i'm using casting for some objects and if the first condition in my boolean expression is false  ,the second condition will give me error and stop my program

*if anything seems to be unclear to you, i will be gratefull for you if you left a comment to let me know.

Comment: thank you , i have mistyped this one.. thanks again :)

Comment: As long as the generated code follows the short-circuit evaluation rules specified in the specifications, then the compiler may generate any code or sequence of instructions it wants, there is no "standard" way.

Comment: you mean by this  , the compiler will start will start with any of the two expression just as a random choice

Comment: Nothing random, the sequencing of the sub-expressions is strict, in your example `a > c` will ***always*** be evaluated first, and `b < s` ***may*** be evaluated afterwards, that's how [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) works. As for the exact implementation details, they are up to the actual implementation. If you want to see how *your* compiler does it, then create a simple program containing your expression, and look at the disassembled instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `&&` operator, the second condition will not be evaluated if the first one is false. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://users.drew.edu/bburd/JavaForDummies4/ShortCircuitEval.pdf).

You can simply check it for yourself by writing two functions that return a `boolean` value and print something to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/sather/docs-1.2/tutorial/conditional.html:

> "And" expressions compute the conjunction of two boolean expressions and return boolean values. The first expression is evaluated and if false, false is immediately returned as the result. Otherwise, the second expression is evaluated and its value returned.
>
> "Or" expressions compute the disjunction of two boolean expressions and return boolean values. The first expression is evaluated and if true, true is immediately returned as the result. Otherwise, the second expression is evaluated and its value returned.

At runtime, if the first expression is false, the second is skipped because the executed code will only go to the next expression if the first is true.

Comment: so the second condition will be skipped even i have  a runtime error in that condition? something like casting an object to another which has no "is a" relationship with.?

Comment: Right, if the first condition is false, the 2nd condition will not be evaluated. Thus, having code to catch an error on the 2nd condition won't matter because the first condition being false prevented it from ever being read.